# sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type map[string]interface {}, a map"

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I'm trying to insert a value of type `map[string]interface` from Golang into a column of type `jsonb` on a Postgresql db. When I'm trying to do it, I encountered this error. I think it has a problem with the data type and I need to convert it to a value that's accepted by `jsonb` somehow, but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm using sqlx for querying the db.

I also can't use `struct` because the keys can be anything, that's why I use `map` here.

```golang
func Insert(ctx context.Context) (id int64, err error) {
  newMap := map[string]interface{}{
    "code": "ABC123",
    "name": "new name",
    "properties": map[string]interface{}{
      "response_status": 1,
      "reposne_message": "success",
    },
  }

  err := sqlx.DB.QueryRowxContext(ctx, query, newMap.properties).Scan($id)
  if err != nil {
    return
  }
  return
}
```

This is the query. The column `properties` has a type of `jsonb`.

```sql
query := `
  INSERT INTO thisTable (properties) VALUES ($1) RETURNING this_table_id
`
```

This is the error message

```bash
sql: converting argument $5 type: unsupported type map[string]interface {}, a map
```

I had tried to convert it by casting it into `jsonb` on the db-side but it doesn't work and throws the same error message.

```sql
query := `
  INSERT INTO thisTable (properties) VALUES ($1::jsonb)
`
```